# Is this equation homogenous or inhomogeous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have the following differential equation in my perturbation theory notes

$y'' + 2y' = -2y$

$y(0) = 0$

It says in the following section that this equation is inhomogeneous. But I thought equations are inhomogenous if they are of the form

$ay'' + by' + cy = F(x)$ with $F(x) \ne 0$

So why is the above equation described as inhomogeneous? Is it a mistake..or is it something to do with a boundary condition being specified..or is it something else?

Comment: I guess it is a misprint.

Comment: It was a misprint, there was a subscript missing on the $y$ term on the RHS.

Answer (score -1):

your first equation $y''+2y'+2y=0$ is homogeneous and has the solution
$y \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}\,{{\rm e}^{-x}}\sin \left( x \right) +{
\it \_C2}\,{{\rm e}^{-x}}\cos \left( x \right) 
$